# What's the java code for showing a report generated by iReport either as pdf or xls?

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, show

What's the java code for showing a report generated by iReport either as pdf or xls? I am using jasperreports.

Answer (score 1):

It's based on the `JRExporter` implementation you use. If you want a PDF:

```
JRExporter exp = new JRPdfExporter();
```

If you want XLS:

```
JRExporter exp = new JRXlsExporter();
```

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporter.html

Answer (score 1):

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("new.xls"));
```